# How to handle only overlays while printing a latex beamer notes

Tags: beamer, overlays, notes

Using overlays and showing multiple graphs in the same slides and even text is really great but I am really wondering how can we show each piece of overlay while printing the slides or notes ? It seems some of the slide can have multiple pages in order to accurately show all the graphs and text especially when we use overlays such as `\only<1-3` and `\only<4-5>`. If it is just a regular text and fills only one page then it should be fine. But often times it is more complex than that. Would anyone clarify what can we do under such circumstances ?

**EDIT: MINIMAL EXAMPLE ADDED**

What I mean here is that on the second slide I have three different tikz picture. Here I didn't include the picture on node (0,0). In my slide I am using the pictures. SO, how can I print all these three pictures on the same page ? In other cases also some of the text doesn't fit on the slides. I hope it is more understandable now.

A minimal working example

```
%\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}

\documentclass[arial,handout]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgf,pgfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{units}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{animate}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

 \tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{ift}
  \setbeamertemplate{items}[square]
}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\LARGE,series=\bfseries}

\definecolor{uibred}{RGB}{170, 0, 0}
\definecolor{uibblue}{RGB}{0, 84, 115}
\definecolor{uibgreen}{RGB}{119, 175, 0}
%\definecolor{uibgreen}{RGB}{50, 105, 0}
\definecolor{uiborange}{RGB}{217, 89, 0}

%% Create a new command called redub for underbraces
\newcommand\redub[2]{%
    \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
    \color{red}%
    \underbrace{\color{currentcolor}#1}_{\color{red}#2}%
    \color{currentcolor}%
}


%Beamer block template
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=uibblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{fg=white,bg=green}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty


%\include{macros}

%\includeonlyframes{current}


\defbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{mycircle}
{
  %\usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
  %\usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0ex}{0ex}{1.5ex}{0ex}
    %\pgfcircle[fill]{\pgfpoint{0pt}{.75ex}}{1.25ex}
    \pgfbox[center,base]{\color{uibblue}\insertenumlabel.}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}
[action]
{\setbeamerfont{item projected}{size=\scriptsize}}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[mycircle]

\begin{document}

%\setbeamertemplate{background}
% {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{slide_bg1}}
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[ifttheme]

\mode<presentation>

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Eulerian Salt Flux Decomposition}

    \only<1-2>{\begin{itemize}
        \item Subtidal Volume discharge rate $Q_f$: through a cross=section A  \\
        $Q_f = \langle\int u.dA \rangle$
        \item Salt transport rate $F_s$ through a cross-section A \\
        $F_s = \langle \int uS.dA \rangle$
    \end{itemize}}
        \onslide<2->Sub-tidal salt flux decomposed into three parts 

    \onslide<2->\begin{align*}
        F  & = \langle \int(u_0+u_E+U_T)(s_0+s_E+s_T)dA \rangle \\
            & \approx \langle \int(u_0s_0+u_Es_E+u_Ts_T)dA \rangle \\
            & = \redub{Q_fs_0}{\mathclap{\text{     River flow     }}} + 
             \redub{F_E}{\substack{\text{Exchange}\\\text{shear dispersion}}} + 
             \redub{F_T}{\substack{\text{tidal osciallatory}\\\text{salt transport}}}
    \end{align*}

    \onslide<3->\begin{itemize}
        \item $u_0$ and $s_0$ tidally and cross-sectionally averaged
        \item $u_E$ and $s_E$ tidally averaged and cross-sectionally varying 
        \item $u_T$ and $s_T$ tidally and cross-sectionally varying
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Age of Water under dye from all Rivers}

    \only<1-3>{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
        \node [](0,0)(start){ hello2};
%       \draw [step=0.5cm,thin,dotted] (-5,-4) grid(5,4);
%       \node [circle]at (-4.5,0){0};
%       \node [circle,radius=0.9cm,fill=red!30,] at (-4.5,0)(a){};
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](-4.3,-0.2)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](-3.3,0)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](-2.5,-0.7)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](-4.,-0.8)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](-4.,-1.2)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](4.3,1.6)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](3.3,2.7)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](1.6,3.5)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](1.3,3.5)circle(0.1cm);      
        \node [rectangle,text width=4cm,red] at (5.5,3) (return) {$Q_2 = 169 A^{0.616}$     \linebreak Mason et. al. 1998};
        \node [rectangle,text width=4cm,red,visible on =<2->] at (5,0) (return) {Smaller near the source     \linebreak Increases away from the source};
        \draw [red,visible on =<3->](-3.3,-1.5) circle(0.7cm);%wolf bay small age
    \end{tikzpicture}}

        \only<4-5>{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [](0,0)(start){hello1};
%   \draw [step=0.5,dotted](-5,-4) grid (5,4);
     \node [rectangle,text width=4cm,red] at (5,0) (return) {Scale different from    \linebreak 2 year inflows};
     \node [rectangle, text width =4cm, red,visible on =<5->] at (5,-2) {Maximum age of 120 days};
     \draw [red] (1.5,-1) ellipse(1cm and 0.6cm);
     \node [rectangle, text width=4cm, red] at (5,3) {Minimum 7 day flow over 10 yr. interval};
    \end{tikzpicture}}  

        %
        \only<6-7>{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [](0,0)(start){hello};
        \node [rectangle, text width=4cm, red, visible on =<7->] at (5,3) {Mean inflows over 10 yr. interval};
        \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is not completely clear to me; can you please try to expand a little? Perhaps adding (the description of) some example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have added a minimal working example and tried to explain what I mean. I hope you understand it.

Comment: Are you aware of the `handout` overlay specification?

Comment: No, could you explain a little bit more.

Comment: @Jdbaba: In specifying overlay options, you can add the `handout:<number>` option. For example, `\only<1-3| handout:1>{content-1}` will print `content-1` that appears in frames 1 to 3 as the first page of the handout; `\only<4-5| handout:2>{content-2}` prints `content-2` which appears in frames 4 and 5 as the second page of the handout; and `\only<6-| handout:0>{content-3}` will instruct beamer not to print `content-3` that appears on frame 6 onwards. Notice that a space is needed between `|` and `handout`.

Comment: @kevin: Thank you so much for the explanation. It is clear to me now.

Comment: @Jdbaba: You're welcome :) It seems in some of your frames there are too much texts/figure that they cannot fit within a single frame in `handout` mode. In those cases, you'll have to either break them into several frames in handout, or use the `article` mode (see Chapter 21.2 of the [Beamer Manual](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf))

Comment: @KevinC I have a quick question. Is it possible to hide some of the onslide options on the handout mode ? For example I have  `\includegraphics<1>[scale=0.5]{figurer/ageconcept1.png} 
 \includegraphics<2>[scale=0.5]{figurer/ageconcept2.png}  
 \includegraphics<3 |handout:1>[scale=0.5]{figurer/ageconcept3.png}`. I want to show only one figure (not all on multiple pages) on the handout. How can I achieve that ? Right two figures are sticking on the sides.

Comment: @Jdbaba: Did you mean not showing `ageconcept1` and `ageconcept2`? In that case just use `\includegraphics<1| handout:0>[scale=.5]{figurer/ageconcept1}`, and similarly for the second figure.

Comment: @KevinC Sounds like your comments are an answer

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Converting my comments above into an answer:

In specifying overlay options, you can add the `handout:<number>` option. For example, `\only<1-3| handout:1>{content-1}` will print `content-1` that appears in frames 1 to 3 as the first page of the handout; `\only<4-5| handout:2>{content-2}` prints `content-2` which appears in frames 4 and 5 as the second page of the handout; and `\only<6-| handout:0>{content-3}` will instruct beamer not to print `content-3` that appears on frame 6 onwards. Notice that a space is needed between `|` and `handout`.

To not show an item/graphic in the handout, simply set `handout:0`.