# How to set the same slide number for all slides in the `allowframebreaks` group?

Tags: beamer, page-breaking, page-numbering

I have `[framebreaks]` frames in a Beamer presentation. I want to have all generated slides there to have the same slide nubmber, e.g., if I have a `listing` or some text that spans across two or more slides, but within the same frame I want to prevent slide number increase until I start a new frame. In the MWE below "Slide 1" should be numbered 1/2 for the first 3 PDF slides, whereas "Slide 2" should be 2/2. Using `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}` or `\setcounter{framenumber}{x}` simply starts counting at current-1 or x. I am aware of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44132), but unless I am missing something, I don't see how I can adapt the material there to my problem at this hour.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
  \mode<presentation>

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

% "Slide 1"
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\begin{itemize}
 \item Foo 
 \item Bar
 \item Baz
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{frame}

% "Slide 2"
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121031) appears to be more related it seems with `\beamber@slidenumber`... how would I use that here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be a solution.

We use a new counter `multipleslide` where we save the current value of the counter `framenumber`

```
\newcounter{multipleslide}
```

We also define two new commands `\multipleframe` and `\restoreframe` to be inserted, respectively, before and after a `frame` with `allowframebreaks`

```
\makeatletter%
\newcommand{\multipleframe}{%
\setcounter{multipleslide}{\value{framenumber}}
\stepcounter{multipleslide}
\patchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@footline}% <cmd>
  {\insertframenumber}% <search>
  {\themultipleslide}% <replace>
  {}% <success>
  {}% <failure>
}
\newcommand{\restoreframe}{%
\patchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@footline}% <cmd>
  {\themultipleslide}% <search>
  {\insertframenumber}% <replace>
  {}% <success>
  {}% <failure>
\setcounter{framenumber}{\value{multipleslide}}%
}
\makeatother%
```

The first one takes care of numbering all the slides with the same number, the latter restores the normal numbering.

The following MWE explains a bit better how it works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
  \mode<presentation>

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{multipleslide}

\makeatletter%
\newcommand{\multipleframe}{%
\setcounter{multipleslide}{\value{framenumber}}
\stepcounter{multipleslide}
\patchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@footline}% <cmd>
  {\insertframenumber}% <search>
  {\themultipleslide}% <replace>
  {}% <success>
  {}% <failure>
}
\newcommand{\restoreframe}{%
\patchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@footline}% <cmd>
  {\themultipleslide}% <search>
  {\insertframenumber}% <replace>
  {}% <success>
  {}% <failure>
\setcounter{framenumber}{\value{multipleslide}}%
}
\makeatother%

\begin{document}

% "Slide 1"
\multipleframe  %<------------------------------------
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\begin{itemize}
 \item Foo
 \item Bar
 \item Baz
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{frame}
\restoreframe  %<------------------------------------

% "Slide 2"
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is the output

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Works like a charm. I am unfamiliar with `etoolbox`... still so many things to learn!

Comment: It used to work for me, but trying this a few years later again this solution doesn't work for me anymore

Comment: I haven't retried recently TBH, maybe newer TeXLive distributions or package distributions changed something that affects it? If I have chance I can retest as well but perhaps @karlkoeller may have some insight