# Same page number for slides using itemize

Tags: beamer, page-numbering, itemize

Is the Antibes theme the problem here? according to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131480/how-to-set-the-same-slide-number-for-all-slides-in-the-allowframebreaks-group), the solution I put in my MWE (below) should do the trick but it doesn't. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/latex-beamer-how-to-get-distinct-page-numbers-when-using-overlays/10786#10786) doesn't work either. I got no error whatsoever, it just compiles flawlessly but it outputs only one slide. It should give three slides with the same page number (ie. 1/1). It's the same if I use Boadilla theme.

Any idea how to get the right output? thanks in advance for your support on this,

MWE:

ps. I just left these packages to check that there was no conflict. I did several tests after commenting one by one and it seems that they are causing no problems at all.

```
\documentclass[compress,final]{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
    \setbeamercovered{transparent=25}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%\makeatletter
%\def\c@slideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
%\makeatother

\newcounter{multipleslide}

\makeatletter%
\newcommand{\multipleframe}{%
    \setcounter{multipleslide}{\value{framenumber}}
    \stepcounter{multipleslide}
    \patchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@footline}% <cmd>
    {\insertframenumber}% <search>
    {\themultipleslide}% <replace>
    {}% <success>
    {}% <failure>
}
\newcommand{\restoreframe}{%
    \patchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@footline}% <cmd>
    {\themultipleslide}% <search>
    {\insertframenumber}% <replace>
    {}% <success>
    {}% <failure>
    \setcounter{framenumber}{\value{multipleslide}}%
}
\makeatother%

\begin{document}

\section{ITEM}
\subsection{item}
\multipleframe
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> item 1
        \item<2-> item 2
        \item<3-> item 3
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\restoreframe

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: remove option "alowframebreaks". Slides will be numbered 1/1, 2/1 and 1/3.

Comment: removing `[allowframebreaks]` produces the 3 slides but with `1/3`, `2/3`, `3/3`, and it should be `1/3` for every slide, any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Maybe it's `frame number` rather than `page number`?

Comment: @egreg thanks! that was the problem, indeed, I confirm that I don't need the solutions I was trying, simply using `frame number` did the trick. If you put that as answer, I'll mark it as such. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `beamer`, `page number` refers to the “physical” page number: any overlay increments the number.

You want to use `frame number`, that's incremented by `\begin{frame}`.