# How to uncover table column with borders

Tags: tables, beamer, overlays

I try to show frame in 4 slides. First 2 are fine, but I fail in showing a table using two slides. Content of first column appears correctly - only on slide 4, but borders around this column are still shown

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
%\documentclass[12pt,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow} %Used for tables with merged cells
\usepackage{collcell} %pdflatex.exe hangs without this one

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Communication Models}

  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item OSI
    \item TCP/IP
  \end{itemize}

  \onslide<3->
  \begin{center}
  %Works almost fine, but first column should disappear fully (not just text)
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\onslide<4->}l<{\onslide<3->}|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Mnemonic}&  \textbf{\#} & \textbf{OSI} & \textbf{TCP/IP}              \\ \hline
    All              &  7           & Application  & \multirow{3}{*}{Application} \\ \cline{1-3}
    People           &  6           & Presentation &                              \\ \cline{1-3}
    Seem             &  5           & Session      &                              \\ \hline
    To               &  4           & Transport    & Transport                    \\ \hline
    Need             &  3           & Network      & Internet                     \\ \hline
    Data             &  2           & Data Link    & \multirow{2}{*}{Link Access} \\ \cline{1-3}
    Processing       &  1           & Physical     &                              \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Instead of:

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\onslide<4->}l<{\onslide<3->}|l|l|l|}
```

I tried to use:

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\onslide<4->}|l<{\onslide<3->}|l|l|l|}
\begin{tabular}{ \ifnum\slideno>3 | \fi >{\onslide<4->}l<{\onslide<3->}|l|l|l|}
```

but first version gives:

```
! Package array Error: >{..} at wrong position: token ignored.
```

and second:

```
! Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\ifnum): `c' used.
```

Is it possible to make first column to be hidden on several slides completely (including borders)?

---

---

### Solution, based on Piet's answer (UPD2)

**Updated solution** (UPD3) uses page-independent `slideinframe` counter, which is counted for each frame separately

This solution uses `\newcolumntype{G}` for first column, which does not appear at slide 3, but appears at slide 4 and handouts.

```
% Add line below to preamble
\def\Gobble#1\EndGobble{}
% UPD3: 3 lines below define slide counter within a frame (found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120940/119704)
\makeatletter
\def\c@slideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother
...
% Add lines below to body (before tabular, and edit tabular definition)
% Next line is to show first column on handouts
\newcolumntype{G}{|l}
% Rules below hide first column on first 3 slides of beamer presentation, no influence on handouts
\only{beamer}{
  % UPD3: Change "page" to "slideinframe"
  %\ifnum\value{page}>3 \newcolumntype{G}{|l}\else
  \ifnum\value{slideinframe}>3 \newcolumntype{G}{|l}\else
  % I would be grateful if someone could describe the magic below :)
  \newcolumntype{G}{@{}>{\Gobble}l<{\EndGobble}@{}}\fi
}
% Apply newcolumntype
\begin{tabular}{G|l|l|l|}
```

---

### Solution based on samcarter's workaround (UPD1)

Draw a rectangle with color, equal to background color
This solution needs fine tuning (position and size of the rectangle)

```
% Add line below to preamble:
\usepackage{tikz}
...
% Add lines to the end of frame:
  \only<beamer>{
    \vspace*{-4.7cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{onlyenv}<3>
        \draw [color=bg, fill=bg] (0,0) rectangle (3.67,4.3); 
      \end{onlyenv}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: I have changed this to a slightly cleaner solution with `\newcolumntype`.**

You cannot put macros in a `tabular` spec that have to be expanded at definition time. You you must make the whole `begin{tabular}{...}` line conditional. And then you still have the first column text that must be swallowed up.

Alternatively, define a new columntype, conditional on the slide number. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow} %Used for tables with merged cells
\usepackage{collcell} %pdflatex.exe hangs without this one

\def\Gobble#1\EndGobble{}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Communication Models}

  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item OSI
    \item TCP/IP
  \end{itemize}

  \onslide<3-4>
  \begin{center}
  \only<3> {\newcolumntype{G}{@{}>{\Gobble}l<{\EndGobble}@{}}}
  \only<4> {\newcolumntype{G}{|l}}

   \begin{tabular}{G|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Mnemonic}&  \textbf{\#} & \textbf{OSI} & \textbf{TCP/IP}              \\ \hline
    All              &  7           & Application  & \multirow{3}{*}{Application} \\ \cline{1-3}
    People           &  6           & Presentation &                              \\ \cline{1-3}
    Seem             &  5           & Session      &                              \\ \hline
    To               &  4           & Transport    & Transport                    \\ \hline
    Need             &  3           & Network      & Internet                     \\ \hline
    Data             &  2           & Data Link    & \multirow{2}{*}{Link Access} \\ \cline{1-3}
    Processing       &  1           & Physical     &                              \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool! That works much cleaner, compared to workaround with rectangle. Unfortunately, I cannot understand how this works (could you please explain Gobble trick?) and [therefore?] cannot make this column appear on handout slides `\documentclass[12pt,handout]{beamer}`, is this possible?

Comment: The slide 3 G column places `\Gobble` before the entry and `\EndGobble` after the entry, so it processes `\Gobble your entry \EndGobble`, which is defined by the `\def` to produce nothing.

Comment: Yeees! I did it! Now handouts do not hide the column! Thanks a lot @Piet
I added `\newcolumntype{G}{|l}` and enclosed your `\if\else\fi` solution in `\only<beamer>{}`

Comment: Could you please help again, @Piet? The solution above doesn't work (doesn't hide a column) if I add (even an empty) frame **before** the one with your answer. Everything is fine if there are frames **after**, despite the same trick doesn't work again (I made another copy of the same frame with your trick and it works for the first frame, but not the second).

Comment: If you add a frame then the numbers must be changed. The 3 must become 4.

Comment: OK, this isn't nice. It's because we use **page numbers** which can change. I now have a better solution wit `\only`. I have updated the solution.

Comment: Instead of changing the numbers manually, you can also use relative overlay instructions. e.g. `<.(1)>` to display only on the current slide.

Comment: Thank you very much! In the meantime I found a `slideinframe` counter, but I like your `\only` solution more. Anyway, trying to understand Gobble magic is still driving me crazy %).

Comment: To see how Gobble works enter this in your document: `\Gobble Here is my text \EndGobble` and see what that does in your document.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: place a rectangle with the same colour as the background over the    table.

EDIT: now with relative overlay instructions - so it should not matter how many slides are inserted before the table.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow} %Used for tables with merged cells
\usepackage{collcell} %pdflatex.exe hangs without this one

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Communication Models}

          \pause

      \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Mnemonic}&  \textbf{\#} & \textbf{OSI} & \textbf{TCP/IP}              \\ \hline
        All              &  7           & Application  & \multirow{3}{*}{Application} \\ \cline{1-3}
        People           &  6           & Presentation &                              \\ \cline{1-3}
        Seem             &  5           & Session      &                              \\ \hline
        To               &  4           & Transport    & Transport                    \\ \hline
        Need             &  3           & Network      & Internet                     \\ \hline
        Data             &  2           & Data Link    & \multirow{2}{*}{Link Access} \\ \cline{1-3}
        Processing       &  1           & Physical     &                              \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}

      \vspace*{-4.21cm}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{onlyenv}<.(1)>
              \draw [color=bg, fill=bg] (0,0) rectangle (2.42,4.2); 
          \end{onlyenv}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \pause
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, at least this works :). I just had to add `\only<beamer>{}` around a rectangle, so that it is not shown on handouts.